# PowerPoint Charts/Graphs - Images in Value Labels

Tags: charts, microsoft-powerpoint, slideshow

I am working on a project to show information about sports teams. I would like to include their logos in the chart's column labels instead of having to only use the abbreviations to represent the team.

How can I get the image to be part of the label without having to manually add and modify if I change something in the chart (I.E. change column order or resize the chart)? Additionally, I would also like to include the date.

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

[image: Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish]

Guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. I have not be able to find a way to get the image into the data table.

Comment: Have you disassembled an actual example of one of these charts in PPT or Excel to see how they were created (ie, IF they were created in the way you want to be able to create them as opposed to, eg, someone just pasting in the logos atop the already created chart)?

Comment: The picture was a mockup of what I want to do. It was not someone’s existing

Comment: OK, thanks. PowerPoint has no way of doing this out of the box. You'll need to decide whether the logos (rather than text or color coded labels) add enough value to make it worthwhile to move them around as needed by changes to the data.